# Is there any reason why chunking the digit span test would not help?

Tags: memory, working-memory, short-term-memory

Is there any reason why chunking the digit span test would not help, and what is the average score without chunking? By chunking I mean any rehearsal besides saying the numbers one time as they appear.

I asked a similar question already:

[Does the digit span test draw on any executive functions besides working memory, if "chunking" is not used?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/18329/does-the-digit-span-test-draw-on-any-executive-functions-besides-working-memory)

Just intrigued why chunking might not work as well (and it's trivial that it won't always work as well), or not at all.

Comment: *"Just intrigued because I score less when I try and chunk! Bluntly, I cannot chunk, and any attempt to do so is either barren or empties my head"*  This question seems off-topic to me due to it "relating to an individual".  In other words you are asking here why chunking doesn't help you.  If you can find references to back the fact that chunking does not help others with digit span tests, this would counteract the answer given in your similar question and make this question on-topic.  Can you find anything like this?

Comment: this isn't a "self-help" question! @ChrisRogers no different to asking "what do low iq scores mean ps i have a low iq"

Comment: @ChrisRogers sorry if i was rude Chris

Comment: @user3293056 "chunking the digit span would not help"...but for what? what are you hoping to _help_?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the effectiveness of chunking depends on (1) test speed and (2) amount of practice.

At low speed simple techniquest benefit almost everyone a little, even with virtually no practice. Quoting from [Dempster and Zinkgraf](https://doi.org/10.1016/0160-2896(82)90014-9)

> Recently, in fact, evidence has been found that questions the validity of the assumption
>   that chunking plays a role in digit-span variance. In one experiment,
>   Lyon (1977) presented 12-item digit sequences to adult subjects for whom conventional
>   digit-span estimates were available, and instructed them to think of each
>   successive group of three digits as a three-digit number. The important result was
>   that subjects with high spans (average = 8.3) benefited just as much from the chunking
>   instructions as those with low spans (average = 6.1). Thus, prompting all subjects to
>   impose a common structure on the lists did not produce the convergence of the two
>   groups that would be expected if chunking was the source of differences between
>   subjects in the high- and low-span groups.

On the other hand

> However, it does seem plausible that the temporal characteristics of
>   the digit-span task (rapid presentation rate and single trial) simply allow little opportunity
>   for chunking, unless the individual is exceptionally adept at creating
>   chunks (Hunt & Love, 1972, pp. 248-250), or has received an extended period of
>   practice ([Ericsson, Chase, & Faloon, 1980](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a084754.pdf); Gates & Taylor, 1925; Martin &
>   Fernberger, 1929). For such an individual, chunking can be a highly successful
>   strategy.

The "extended practice" mentioned there involves associative techniques not merely chunking.